# unable to send JSON data using POST method through API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to access the private API through AWS API Gateway that has lambda integrated.
So I am using **DefaultRequest** object with AWS4Signer to sign the http request and hit the private API url.

Although, I am able to hit the URL, but unable to send the JSON data, on the receiving lambda in the handleRequest() I am getting an empty JSON {}. Below is the code I am using.

```
private static void doAswSigFour(String url, DefaultRequest<Void> request) {
        AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setRegionName(US_EAST_ONE);
        signer.setServiceName(EXECUTE_API);
        signer.setEndpointPrefix(url);
        String accessKeyID = System.getenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
        String secretKey = System.getenv(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
        String sessionKey = System.getenv(AWS_SESSION_TOKEN);
        BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(accessKeyID, secretKey, sessionKey);
        signer.sign(request, basicSessionCredentials);
    }
    
private static DefaultRequest<Void> createAPIGWGetRequest(String finalUrl, String jsonString) {
        DefaultRequest<Void> request = new DefaultRequest<Void>(EXECUTE_API);
        request.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_SLASH_JSON);
        request.setEndpoint(URI.create(finalUrl));
        request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
        request.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes()));
        return request;
    }
```

In the above code jsonString is my actual JSON in string. I am not sure if there is some other way to send the data.

Edit 1:
Adding invoking functionality code

```
private static String invokeAPI(int trackerStatusAPIMaxWaitTime, DefaultRequest<Void> request) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setRequestTimeout(trackerStatusAPIMaxWaitTime);
        clientConfiguration.setSocketTimeout(trackerStatusAPIMaxWaitTime);
        clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(trackerStatusAPIMaxWaitTime);
        Response<AmazonWebServiceResponse<String>> response = new AmazonHttpClient(clientConfiguration)
                .requestExecutionBuilder().request(request).errorResponseHandler(new ErrorResponseHandler())
                .execute(new StringResponseHandler());
        return response.getAwsResponse().getResult();
    }
```